# C programming comparing strings from file

Tags: c, file, text

Right so i have a program that will find a strings place in a file, and the line it belongs to. Now the Find works fine but the string compare has a big problem i cannot get my head around, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
int loop, line;
char str[512];
char string[512];
FILE *fd = fopen("Student Passwords.txt", "r");
if (fd == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    return -1;
}
printf("Enter the string: ");
scanf("%s",string);
printf("Enter the line number to read : ");
scanf("%d", &line);

for(loop = 0;loop<line;++loop){
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd);
}
printf("\nLine %d: %s\n", line, str);
str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
if(strcmp(string,str) == 0 )
 {
 printf("Match");
 }
     else
     {
     printf("Nope");
     }
fclose(fd);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Someone told me to use strlen, which i of course inserted into the code but i think it just makes it worse, i am not sure what to do now can i have some help?

Text file:

```
Password 
abcdefg 
Star_wars 
jedi
Weapon 
Planet 
long 
nail 
car 
fast 
cover 
machine 
My_little
Alone
Love
Ghast
```

Thanks
Edit: Input: Random word , Input: line number. Program will go to the line chosen and scan the string stored there, and compare it with the input string. Output: Either Match or Nope.

Edit: Input: Password, 1 Output: Match , Input: Password, 2 Output: Nope.

Comment: What's the problem ? What output do you get for what input and what out put do you expect ?

Comment: try to use a debugger, that's what it's made for

Comment: `if(str[len=strlen(str)-1] == '\n') str[len] = '\0';` better than it.

Comment: The program you posted in your question works fine here.

Comment: Really?, it doesn't work on mine, the only one i see working is jedi

Comment: Try replacing `fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd)` with `fscanf(fd,"%511s",str)` and see what happens.

Comment: @user3227362, because rest of your words in the file have spaces after them. see my answer.

Comment: Wait, what? You don't just change the whole question via an edit! Ask a new question!

Comment: Well, that edit makes all the comments (never mind the accepted answer) look really surreal.

Comment: Actually I want this question to be kept private, but since deleting doesn't work I've decided to just mask it

Comment: you know people can see your edits, right?

Comment: But they aren't searching for the question, therefore it is perfect

Comment: @user3227362: You don't ask *private* questions on the Internet. Especially not on StackOverflow, aiming to help all programmers.

Comment: I like how all changes I have made have been reverted.

Comment: @user3227362: What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program works fine for me except that your text file have trailing spaces after some words. but your user input do not have spaces. Try to print the lengths of the user input and read line and you can find out.

**Remove all trailing spaces from your text file and there should not be any problem.**

Also as others have mentioned, it is good to use similar input functions in your code. you can use `fgets` for user input also.

Comment: Works a charm, thanks.

Comment: What was the initial question?